# Linux shell scripting: unexpected variable behavior

Tags: shell, shell-script, string-manipulation, echo

I have a variable `$myvar` that contains two lines, and I want to put first of them into a new variable.

When I try:

```
$ myvar1 = $(echo $myvar | head -n 1)
```

It doesn't work because echo doesn't output newlines as I am expecting.

Obviously I can do this:

```
$ myvar1 = $(echo $myvar | cut -d " " -f 1)
```

It will work as echo's output contains one word on the first line and one word on the second.

I have two questions:

1. Why does echo print spaces instead of line breaks?
2. Is it possible to make it easily or more correct (I'm not a professional in shell scripting, maybe I'm missing something here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the argument to `echo` in quotation marks to retain whitespace properly.

```
echo "$myvar"
```

Otherwise the whitespace-separated elements of the value will be treated as individual arguments to `echo`.

```
$ ls -1
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Movies
Music
Pictures
Sites

$ myvar="$( ls -1 )"

$ echo $myvar
Desktop Documents Downloads Movies Music Pictures Sites

$ echo "$myvar"
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Movies
Music
Pictures
Sites
```

---

To get the first line of something, `head -n1` works perfectly. It depends on your requirements and the possible values whether that is actually what you need.